# Whitelist and identity tracking of NFT holders

Tags: nft, oracles, opensea, erc-1155

I am working on ERC1155 NFT collection and because of the regulation related to the project I am part of, we are required to allow only certain users to hold the NFT.
For that reason, I want to implement a mechanism to track the holders' identity and allow only an updated list of addresses to hold the NFT.

Until now I designed the following solution:

**Overview:**

Implement a whitelist in the contract and allow transferring only for those addresses. When a user wants to buy the NFT, he needed to register on a website (link presented in the collection description) and then his address is added to the whitelist and he can buy the NFT in any marketplace.

**Technical Details:**

Whitelist - Stored either internally or in an external server. The whitelist validated in `_beforeTokenTransfer` function.

- External server: whitelist stored in an external server, data received by oracle 3rd party service, data signed by certificate to ensure validity. This solution saves blockchain fees, but costs fees for the `oracle` service and is less secure.
- Internally: the addresses saved inside the contract in the `mapping` object. Costs lots of fees because of the amount of data (might reach thousands of addresses), more secure.

Website - The link for registration will be presented in the contract description. Inside the website, the customer will fill in the required data and his wallet address.

**Pros:**

- Allow account tracking

**Cons:**

- Might be blocked by marketplaces
- Not private as web3 should be
- Cumbersome for customers
- High fees
- Less secure in case of external server whitelist

I would like to get your opinion about the solution, any kind of recommendation or even lead for investigation will help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is better done as some kind of development work. You may wish to consult a professional who can advise you in a much better capacity. Your requirements will vary and change over time, so it's better you work with a developer and have them develop some PoCs for you to evaluate.

What I will say is that it's probably easier to allow some kind of white list / pre mint to ensure i) only approved addresses can mint a NFT and ii) only approved addresses can interact with the NFT (i.e buy/sell/hold) - a smart contract can have this functionality built in.